# How to repeatedly subset data and perform functions across columns in R?

Tags: r

I am looking to select samples with the same label in one column and perform a subtraction within that group's largest and smallest distance numbers (distance numbers being sample's data in different columns) across the group with the same label, however I am not sure how to select the samples with duplicate labels in one column and then perform a subtraction based on their data in other columns.

My data looks like this:

```
Start number  End Number Region label 
     1            2        A
     3            4        A
     5            6        B
```

I am trying to code for region A samples to be selected and for 4-1=3 to be completed (smallest start number subtracted from largest end number), and repeating this for each region. So it would output this:

```
Start number  End Number Region label   Total region distance
     1            2        A                  3
     3            4        A                  3
     5            6        B                 ...
```

At the moment I have tried using the `match()` function to select duplicates and then use `min(df$Start.number)` and `max(df$End.number)` however I am unsure how to make this work and repeat for each region.

I have also tried looking at similar questions and applying their answers but I get errors:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df$distance <- NA 
df %>%
    gather(key, value, -region) %>%
    group_by(region) %>%
    df$distance = max(df$Start) - min(df$End) 

Error in df %>% gather(key, value, -region) %>% group_by(region) %>% df$distance = max(df$Start) -  : 
  could not find function "%>%<-"
In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your use of `dplyr`, you have an error for the last line. For defining a new column, you have to use `mutate` as below

```r
df = data.frame(labels = c("A","A","B"),
                s = c(1,3,5),
                e = c(2,4,6))

df %>% group_by(labels) %>% mutate(Diff = max(e) - min(s)) 

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   labels [2]
  labels     s     e  Diff
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A          1     2     3
2 A          3     4     3
3 B          5     6     1
```

If you want to pass all these operations into your dataframe and get a new column `Diff`, you have to do:

```r
df <- df %>% group_by(labels) %>% mutate(Diff = max(e) - min(s))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will tick answered when the timer allows. I have used this and it has given no errors, however on viewing my data it also doesn't show a new column - is there a way to ensure mutate is producing a new column in my df/dataframe?

Comment: It's because my code is in "viewing". If you want to passed all changes in df, you have to attribute all this code to df. I will edit my answer to show you.